# Python - find _any_ and _all_ matches in a nested list, and return the indices

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists, renpy

Okay, so this is a bit of both Python 2.7, and Ren'Py, so bear with me (I'm rusty, so I might just be doing something incredibly stupid)

I have an input:

`input default "0" length 20 value VariableInputValue('playstore_search')`

This goes on to run a function to check for matches in (currently one) nested list:

```
if playstore_search.strip():
    $ tempsearch = playstore_search.strip()
    text tempsearch:
        color "#000"
        yalign .5 # this is just temporary to show me what the tempsearch looks like
    $ realtimesearchresult = realtime_search(tempsearch,playstore_recommended)
    if realtimesearchresult:
        text "[realtimesearchresult]":
            color "#000"
            yalign .6
```

This goes on to call this function:

```
def realtime_search(searchterm=False,listname=False):
    if searchterm and listname:
        indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(listname) if searchterm in s]
        if indices:
            return indices
```

And, this is a modified list of what it searches:

```
default playstore_recommended = [
            ['HSS','Studio Errilhl','hss'],
            ['Making Movies','Droid Productions','makingmovies'],
            ['Life','Fasder','life'],
            ['xMassTransitx','xMTx','xmasstransitx'],
            ['Parental Love','Luxee','parentallove'],
            ['A Broken Family','KinneyX23','abrokenfamily'],
            ['Inevitable Relations','KinneyX23','inevitablerelations'],
            ['The DeLuca Family','HopesGaming','thedelucafamily'],
            ['A Cowboy\'s Story','Noller72','acowboysstory']
]
```

Now, if I search for `hss`, it'll find that - and if I search for `makingmovies` it'll find that - however, if I search for `droid` (or `Droid` as it isn't case-insensitive currently) it won't find anything.

So, this is at least a twofold question:
1. How do I make this whole thing case-insensitive
2. How do I make it match partial strings

**EDIT:**

Okay, so stuff is now sort of working. However, there are still some issues. The complete list to match against is quite a bit more complex than what was posted above, and it seems that it doesn't match on string hits "in the middle of a string" - just on the first word. So, if I have something like this:

```
[
 ['This is a test string with the words game and move in it'],
 ['This is another test string, also containing game']
]
```

and I search for "game", one would expect two results. But I get 0. If, however, I search for "this", I get two results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend converting the entries in the nested-list to lowercase first and then search for the term using `find()`. Consider following function:

```
myListOfLists = [
            ['HSS','Studio Errilhl','hss'],
            ['Making Movies','Droid Productions','makingmovies'],
            ['Life','Fasder','life'],
            ['xMassTransitx','xMTx','xmasstransitx'],
            ['Parental Love','Luxee','parentallove'],
            ['A Broken Family','KinneyX23','abrokenfamily'],
            ['Inevitable Relations','KinneyX23','inevitablerelations'],
            ['The DeLuca Family','HopesGaming','thedelucafamily'],
            ['A Cowboy\'s Story','Noller72','acowboysstory']
]

searchFor = 'hss'
result = [ [ l.lower().find(searchFor) == 0 for l in thisList ] for thisList in myListOfLists ]
```

Using above code, value of `result` is:

```
[[True, False, True],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False]]
```

If you wish to find just one boolean value from the entire list of lists do:

```
any([any(r) for r in result])
```

If you use `searchFor = 'droid'`, it should return `True` as well.

---

To find index of `True`, I recommend using `where` command from `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.where(result)
```

For example, `searchFor = 'life'`, value of `idx` will be:

```
(array([2, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 2], dtype=int64))
```

To find index without using `numpy` (not as elegant):

```
indices = [ [idx if val else -1 for idx, val in enumerate(r) ] for r in result ]
```

This will give positive values corresponding to index where match occurs, else will give `-1`.

```
[[-1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1],
 [0, -1, 2],
 [-1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1]]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, it helps a bit, perhaps, but what this does is return a boolean value - which is completely useless to me unless I can fetch the index(es) for where those booleans were found, or the whole inner list-item(s)

Comment: Thanks for the update - I will test, and see what I get out of it :)

Comment: and... numpy is not available, so is there a way without using numpy?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Have added a non-numpy version, but it isn't as elegant as `where`.

Comment: yeah, I figured that out on my own (but numpy is not available as a module in Renpy, so not an option). However, I've found another problem - it seems that the string-match only matches on first word of string - I will update my question a bit

Comment: I had to modify the `l.lower().find(searchFor) == 0` to `l.lower().find(searchFor) >= 0` to find everything in the string, not just the first word, but other than that this was a great help!

Comment: Thats great! Glad I could help.